# Change Color of RadComboBox

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

When I use Office2007-Skin for the Telerik-Controls, the RadComboBox would have in normal-mode a blue color:

[image]

I am searching for a way, that the RadComboBox looks like:

[image]

I want only change the blue color of the whole RadComboBox.

I cannot change the Skin, because it is used/necessary for other controls.

Can I change this via styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles to your custom css file:

```
div.RadComboBox .rcbReadOnly .rcbInputCellLeft,
div.RadComboBox .rcbFocused .rcbReadOnly .rcbInputCellLeft,
div.RadComboBox .rcbHovered .rcbReadOnly .rcbInputCellLeft
{
  background-position: inherit;
}
```

It will override the default background of the combo input

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it via styling. If you like to change the colors of your control you should override the CSS in the style.

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-appearance-css-selectors.html) you can find the elements of the combobox.
Do not forget to add `!important` in your CSS lines code otherwhise it may not work.

Comment: You can make selectors heavier than the built-in without !important. A year later you will suffer from these !important hacks.